# Field is not updating after JSON request on knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Sometimes user will fill manually the input local, name, age and etc or they will call ajax and fill automatically.
I'm trying to update a field dynamically after json request:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (well) {
    if (well) {
        $("[name=local]").attr({'value': well.local, disabled: true})
        $("[name=name]").attr({'value': well.name, disabled: true})
        $("[name=age]").attr({'value': well.age, disabled: true})
    }
}
```

And there are fields which automatically fills up when I type name + age

```
<g:textField name="local" value="${well.local}" data-bind="value: local"/>
<g:textField name="name" value="${well.name}" data-bind="value: name"/>
<g:textField name="age" value="${well.age}" data-bind="value: age"/>


<g:textField name="nameAge" value="${well.nameAge}" disabled="disabled" data-bind="value: nameAge, attr:{ 'value': nameAge}""/>
<g:hiddenField name="nameAge" data-bind="value: nameAge, attr:{ 'value': nameAge}"/>
```

This wont work after json put the values, but only typing.

```
self.nameAge= ko.computed(function () {
    return self.name() + " - " + self.age();
});
```

What can I do to this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the view model from the element, for examples:

```
 $.getJSON(url, function (well) {
    if (well) {
       var vm=ko.dataFor($("[name=local]")[0]);
        vm.local(well.local);
        vm.age(well.age);
        vm.name(well.name);
    }
 }
```

Or you can try this (i dont have sure):

```
  $.getJSON(url, function (well) {
     if (well) {
        $("[name=local]").attr({'value': well.local, disabled: true}).change()
        $("[name=name]").attr({'value': well.name, disabled: true}).change()
        $("[name=age]").attr({'value': well.age, disabled: true}).change();
}
```

XD